# Will the sign for a cave become gray when completed?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have several white signs for a cave on my map.

Should they become gray when I have looted/found everything inside?
Is it mandatory to find 100% of all possible items inside the cave or do I have to find at least the main treasure chest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entrance markers do not appear to grey out. Even caves that have a quest in them, such as the cave at the Clan Tordaaroch Forge, which has a very clear "main chest," doesn't grey out when "completed."

Comment: I've to add that there're cave symbols with little monster heads next by. Those grey out after you've done them

Comment: Those aren't caves. Those are monster dens. They look similar but are mechanically different

Comment: Even after I cleared Dragonslayers Grotto completely (I'm quite sure I did) and found the armor diagrams, the symbol didn't grey out